# Как суммировать *n количество входящих значений между собой в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как написать функцию, чтобы переменная `sum_all` суммировала все входящие значения?

```
def sum_all(*numbers):
    print(numbers, type(numbers))

sum_all(1, 8)
(1, 8) <class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: А чем вас встроенная “sum()” не устраивает?

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написал в комментарии MaxU, такая функция уже есть - [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

```
print(sum(numbers))
```

Но если хочется именно свой велосипед, то можно например так

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def sum_all(*numbers):
    return reduce(add, numbers)
```

Или так

```
def sum_all(*numbers):
    acc = 0
    for n in numbers:
        acc += n
    return acc
```